# downloading data from ftp using Matlab

Tags: matlab, ftp

I need to download a lots of data from Ftp server. Now I want to use matlab for this task

My ftp address is 
    http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2008.03.17/

Filenames are:

"MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.005.2008080122921.hdf" "MOD09GA.A2008077.h22v05.005.2008080122814.hdf "

Data will get saved in a folder in drive E.

I want to download the file using Matlab. In this way I want to download data from the ftp server.

Waiting for your kind help. 
Thanks in Advance

thank you for your code.but there is a problem.i just need 2data that are below: "MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.005.2008080122921.hdf" "MOD09GA.A2008077.h22v05.005.2008080122814.hdf "

but i need just this ID of that data, to eliminate the extra letters:
"MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.hdf"
 "MOD09GA.A2008077.h22v05.hdf "

I want to have 2 data through 313 data. how can do that? 
please help.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you're downloading using HTTP, not FTP.

You can have Matlab copy the contents of the URL to a local file:

```
url = 'http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2008.03.17/MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.005.2008080122921.hdf'
urlwrite(url, 'tmp.hdf');
```

then to see what's in the file:

```
hdfinfo('tmp.hdf')
```

Answer (score 1):

As dpwe already said, you are not technically downloading via FTP.
However here is a solution tailored to your case, which first gets all the filenames you want, namely the ".*hdf" files. It then just loops over all found *.hdf files and downloads them to 'localPath'.

This is definitely not the easiest or cleanest way to do this, but it works and it should fit your needs, I hope.

```
% URL you want to grab from - has to end with a /
URL = 'http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09GA.005/2008.03.17/';
% Local path on your machine
localPath = 'E:/myfolder/';

% Read html contents and parse file names with ending *.hdf
urlContents = urlread(URL);
ret = regexp(urlContents, '"\S+.hdf"', 'match');

% Loop over all files and download them
for k=1:length(ret)
    filename = ret{k}(2:end-1);
    filepathOnline = strcat(URL, filename);
    filepathLocal = fullfile(localPath, filename);
    urlwrite(filepathOnline, filepathLocal);
end
```

Comment: thank you for your code.but there is a problem.i just need 2data that are below: "MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.005.2008080122921.hdf" "MOD09GA.A2008077.h22v05.005.2008080122814.hdf "

but i need just this ID of that data, to eliminate the extra letters:
"MOD09GA.A2008077.h23v05.hdf"
 "MOD09GA.A2008077.h22v05.hdf "

 I want to have 2 data through 313 data. how can do that? 
please help.